# Why do decorators have to be declared before they're called, but functions don't?

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following example in Python 2.7:

```
import time
@timing
def my_test_function():
    return 5+5
def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print '%s function took %0.3f ms' % (f.func_name, (time2-time1)*1000.0)
        return ret
    return wrap
```

This fails. 
`NameError: name 'timing' is not defined`

However, this does not fail, obviously:

```
def a():
    result = b()
    return result
def b():
    return 'foo'
```

If decorators are functions, what's the difference here?

Comment: Try to call `a()` before `b`'s definition, then it will complain about `b()`.

Comment: I am not sure how you're doing it: https://ideone.com/5c28yM, https://ideone.com/Y3E7bN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions *do* have to be declared before they are called.  The only difference is that decorators are usually called earlier than other functions.

In your example, the decorator is called when `my_test_function` is created (likely import time) whereas `b` doesn't get called until `a` is called.

If you did the following, you'd see a `NameError` just like the decorator case:

```
def a():
    result = b()
    return result

a()  # Call `a` before `b` has been defined.

def b():
    return 'foo'
```

Comment: But they only have to be declared before if the function is called outside of another function, right? I defined `z` above both of those and called it, it worked.

Comment: @Ares -- Basically, the rule is that everything has to be declared before it is referenced.  The key to remembering this is that lines of code aren't executed in order of their line number (lines of code inside a function aren't executed until it is called for example).

Comment: when are references collected? When the program starts?

Comment: @Ares -- Sorry, I'm not following.  What do you mean by "when are references collected"?  Objects (including functions) are created with their line of code executes.  So, (assuming no errors), my example code would basically be "Create function `a`, then call `a`, then create function `b`".  However, since `b` hasn't been created when `a` is called, there _is_ an error.

Comment: I'm asking if it moves from top to bottom, defining variables and functions, as well as calling any functions that are at the top level, then returns to `main` and actually executes?

I'm used to Java and C# where you can't just throw calls to functions in floating space, they have to be in a function.

Comment: @Ares: you should remember that at any time after the declaration of b we can say (for example) `a = b`.  Then calling `a()` will invoke the function `b`.  Python is a dynamic language, C# and Java are static languages.

Comment: @Ares -- It reads from top to bottom executing statements.  Some of those statements create functions or classes in the current namespace (`def`, `class`).  Some of those statements assign values to names (`a = 'hello world'`).  Some of those statements may call functions `b = func()`.  But any statement which depends on another variable needs to have that other variable defined beforehand -- otherwise you'll get a `NameError` (or an `UnboundLocalError` if you're in a function's scope).

Comment: Thanks. That's much clearer to me. Like I said, used to Java and C#.